# Move to new attribute in XML String

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I'm trying to move to another attribute in an xml element but am not having much luck doing this.

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
   <finances> 
       <financial no="0" id="431" rowID="0" ddlValue="Return" ddlNote="Post Dated" ddBranch="" ddType="" /> 
   </finances>
```

Code :

```
Dim child = 0
child = childRow.RowIndex
Dim hidden = CType(gvChild.DataKeys(child)("id"), Integer)

For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//financial/@id")
    If node.Value = hidden.ToString Then
       If Not doc.SelectSingleNode("//financial/@ddlNote").InnerText.Equals("") Then
             LblErr.Text = doc.SelectSingleNode("//financial/@ddlNote").InnerText
       End If

    End If
Next
```

Basically, when the id equals what's on my form I want it to move to the ddlNote attribute and display the value from it. It triggers the first if statement, when it matches up with the id that's on the form it moves to the inner if statement, but the inner if statement won't trigger. How would I move to that attribute (seeing as I'm starting at the id attribute, how would I move to ddlNote)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is one line above the `if` statement that doesn't trigger. Your xpath is selecting attributes, so in the first `if` you're selecting the value of the attribute. Simply repeat it on the second `if` and select the value instead of the inner text:

```
If node.Value = hidden.ToString Then
   If Not doc.SelectSingleNode("//financial/@ddlNote").Value.Equals("") Then
         LblErr.Text = doc.SelectSingleNode("//financial/@ddlNote").Value
   End If
End If
```

...BUT I would change your approach, first because you can use one node for both `if`s and second because with your actual code, if the XML has more than one  node, you will always get the ddlNote attribute of the first one if it is not blank. So I would do something like this:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//financial")
    If node.Attributes("id").Value = hidden.ToString Then
        If Not node.Attributes("ddlNote").Value.Equals("") Then
            LblErr.Text = node.Attributes("ddlNote").Value
        End If
    End If
Next
```

You just need to read the node once and then access it's attributes by name. Remember to use the `value` property, as `innerText` gets the full text of the node and subnodes.

**EDIT:** Even shorter:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes(String.Format("//financial[@id={0}]", hidden.ToString)
    If Not node.Attributes("ddlNote").Value.Equals("") Then
        LblErr.Text = node.Attributes("ddlNote").Value
    End If
Next
```

You can use XPath to directly select the node that has the attribute value you are searching.

Comment: I think I've found a solution, very similar to the last part you posted here, thanks for your help!